# Javascript - ES6 export all

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I don't quite understand [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)'s `export * from …;`. Is the `...` supposed to a class, a file... both?

Also, if I have a bunch of variables e.g.

```
const a = "something"
const b = "something else"
```

is it possible to export it using the `export * from ...` somehow, or is it better to just prepend `export` on each variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `...` is suppose to be a string literal module identifier.

---

It's better to prepend each with an export, or do something like:

```
const a = "something";
const b = "something else";
// ... etc

export {
    a,
    b,
    c,
    d
    // etc
};
```

Comment: then does that other file need to have exports in it as well? Or will the `export *` do the exporting for it?

Comment: The other file also has to have exports; if you `export * from 'myModule'` that's just passing through `myModule`'s exports through your module.

Comment: Strictly speaking its supposed to be a string literal containing a module identifier.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for the heads up; I have updated the answer to reflect that.